# TCP Socket file transfer

Tags: python, sockets, buffer, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a secure transfer file program using Python and AES and i've got a problem i don't totally understand. I send my file by parsing it with 1024 bytes chunks and sending them over but the server side who receive the data crashes ( I use AES CBC therefore my data length must be a multiple of 16 bytes ) and the error i get says that it is not.

I tried to print the length of the data sent by the client on the client side and the length of the data received on the server and it shows that the client is sending exactly 1024 bytes each time like it's supposed to, but the server side shows that at some point in time, a received packet is not and so less than 1024 bytes ( for example 743 bytes ).

I tried to put a time.sleep(0.5) between each socket send on the client side and it seems to work. Is it possible that it is some kind of socket buffer failure on the server side ? That too much data is being send too fast by the client and that it breaks somehow the socket buffer on the server side so the data is corrupted or vanish and the recv(1024) only receive a broken chunk? That's the only thing i could think of, but this may also be completely false, if anyone has an idea of why this is not working properly it would be great ;)

Following my idea i tried :

```
    self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 32768000)
    print socket.SO_RCVBUF
```

I tried to put a 32mbytes buffer on the server side but On Windows XP it shows 4098 on the print and on linux it shows only 8. I don't know how i must interpret this, the only thing i know is that it seems that it doesn't have a 32mbytes buffer so the code doesn't work.

Well it's been a really long post, i hope some of you had the courage to read it all to here ! i'm totally lost there so if anyone has any idea about this please share it :D

Thanks to Faisal my code is here :

Server Side: ( count is my filesize/1024 )

```
while 1:
    txt=self.s.recv(1024)
    if txt == " ":
        break       
    txt = self.cipher.decrypt(txt)
    if countbis == count:
        txt = txt.rstrip()
    tfile.write(txt)
    countbis+=1
```

Client side :

```
while 1:
    txt= tfile.read(1024)
    if not txt:
        self.s.send(" ")
        break
    txt += ' ' * (-len(txt) % 16)
    txt = self.cipher.encrypt(txt)
    self.s.send(txt)
```

Thanks in advance,

Nolhian

Comment: It'd be easier to figure out what's wrong if you posted the code around your recv() call. Assuming you call recv() once per transmission, you should know that you can't expect to get all 1024 bytes of your sent data in a single call to recv(); you need to loop on calling recv() and concatenating to a buffer until you've received the 1024 bytes you expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to network programming! You've just fallen into the same mistaken assumption that *everyone* makes the first time through in assuming that client sends & server recives should be symmetric. Unfortunately, this is not the case. The OS allows reception to occur in arbitrarily sized chunks. It's fairly easy to work around though, just buffer your data until the amount you've read in equals the amount you wish to receive. Something along the lines of this will do the trick:

```
buff=''
while len(buff) < 1024:
    buff += s.recv( 1024 - len(buff) )
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't fall into this (probably because I read a lot of code and Steven's network programming book before writing my first socket using code). Maybe you need to change _everyone_ to _almost everyone_. ;-P

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation ! Moreover i've implemented your lines into my program and that works perfectly now ;)

Answer (score 3):

TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't conserve message boundaries, as you have just discovered.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out you're probably processing an incomplete message. You need to either have fixed sized messages or have a delimiter (don't forget to escape your data!) so you know when a complete message has been received.

Answer (score 1):

What TCP can guarantee is that all your data arrives, in the right order, *at some point*. (Unless something unexpected happens, by which it won't arrive.) But it's very possible that the data you send will still arrive in chunks. Much of it is because of limited send- and receive-buffers. What you should do is to continue doing your `recv` calls until you have enough data to process it. You might might have to call `send` multiple times; use its return value to keep track of how much data has been sent/buffered so far.

When you do `print socket.SO_RCVBUF`, you actually print the symbolic SO_RCVBUF *contant* (except that Python doesn't really have constants); the one used to tell `setsockopt` what you want to change. To get the current value, you should instead call `getsockopt`.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot along with Rakis's answer. I tried to set your answer as an accepted one alongside Rakis's one but it seems i can just set only one, that's too bad :(

Answer (score 1):

Not related to TCP (as that has been answered already), but appending to a string repeatedly will be rather inefficient if you're expecting to receive a lot. It might be better to append to a list and then turn the list into a string when you finished receiving by using `''.join(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

For many applications, the complexities of TCP are neatly abstracted by Python's [asynchat](http://docs.python.org/library/asynchat.html) module.

Comment: Your answer is true, but not really helpful in its current terse format; if you expand with an example, I'll upvote, and so will others (probably).

Comment: Given that `asynchat` is a pretty unfortunate example of late-1990's Standard Library programming that no one ever actually uses, it might not get any upvotes even if explained! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the nice snippet of code that I wrote some time ago, may be not the best , but it could be good example of big files transfer over the local network. http://setahost.com/sending-files-in-local-network-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above

> TCP is a stream protocol

You can try this code, where the data is your original data, you can read it from the file or user input

Sender

```
import socket as s
sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((addr,5000))
sock.sendall(data)
finish = t.time()
```

Receiver

```
import socket as s
sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("", 5000))
sock.listen(1)
conn, _ = sock.accept()
pack = []
while True:
    piece = conn.recv(8192)
    if not piece:
        break
    pack.append(piece.decode())
```